# Do credit card companies start to spam me like crazy after I applied for a credit card and got rejected?

Tags: credit-card

Because that's what's happening to me right now. I got rejected a few months ago, and now I'm getting offers like crazy..

I haven't ever gotten one before, and am still a dependent on my parents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that its not because you were rejected several months before, but because your credit report started showing some activity **and** you fit the filtering criteria (which are pretty low in some cases) for those "preapproved" offers.

Comment: +1. Before he applied he had no credit history and so was automatically filtered out.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting credit card spam mail? Welcome to the world. It's not anything you did, specifically -- it's merely a function of your existence.